# Truncate Database Mail table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, database-mail

We have been having some drive space issues on our SQL server (2005) and I just ran some queries on the `sys.allocation_units` table and found that we have 26GB of database mail attachments.  Apparently we have just been stashing this away in our `msdb` without any kind of clean-up for a couple years.

So I attempted using `sysmail_delete_mailitems_sp` but we're filling up our log and it's hitting our space limitation. I looked in this sys sproc and all it is really doing is running

```
DELETE FROM sysmail_allitems
```

with some parameters and error handling. This is a system view that I'm assuming deletes from a collection of sysmail_xyz tables.

We do not need *any* of this old mail data. Everything we mail is already logged and archived in our application layer. Can I just run

```
TRUNCATE TABLE sysmail_allitems
```

It's a view but it's being DELETE'd so I'm wondering if I can TRUNCATE also. If not maybe I can

```
TRUNCATE TABLE sysmail_attachments
```

but I'm afraid I'll orphan something that will break my system. Any suggestions?

Comment: Offtopic, not a programming question. Try the DBA site.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot truncate a view.

Comment: You can't truncate a view. How would it work if you truncated a view that referenced 6 tables? Which of those tables would it truncate? You will have to delete this data in batches so it doesn't overload your log files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could delete in chunks?

- Determine a date far back in the past for which you know there aren't any mails present in `msdb`
- Construct a `WHILE` loop to execute `sysmail_delete_mailitems_sp` for that date (`@sent_before=@loop_date`), then increment that date
- And so on until the present

That way you wouldn't fill up the log as much...